# Как реализовать логику расчета и отображение результата при вызове второго окна?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlineedit, qtextedit

Проблема состоит в том, что есть определенное вводимое значение в `textEdit`, данные из которой нужно считать и подставить в формулу, после которую вывести в `lineEdit`.

Я всячески пытался, мне бы понять принцип действия в данном моменте, чтобы я понял, как считать и после подставить значение в формулу и полученный результат вывести.

Как осуществить вычисления при помощи кнопки pushButton используя значение из textEdit для вывода результат в поле lineEdit?

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from FirstW import Ui_Dialog
from SecondW import Ui_Other


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

def openSecondW():
    global Other
    Other = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Other()
    ui.setupUi(Other)
    Dialog.show()
    Other.show()

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(openSecondW)
  
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В данном только реализован переход между кнопкой и вторым окном, так вот, мне требуется именно во втором окне сделать вычисления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**FirstW**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    
    # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'FirstW.ui'
    #
    # Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
    #
    # WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
    # run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.
    
    
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
    
    class Ui_Dialog(object):
        def setupUi(self, Dialog):
            Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
            Dialog.resize(1097, 703)
            self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
            self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 861))
            self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
            self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 20, 471, 51))
            self.textEdit_3.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
            self.textEdit_3.setAcceptDrops(False)
            self.textEdit_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
            self.textEdit_3.setAutoFillBackground(True)
            self.textEdit_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
            self.textEdit_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
            self.textEdit_3.setMidLineWidth(1)
            self.textEdit_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.textEdit_3.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
            self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(True)
            self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 351, 51))
            self.textEdit_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.textEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
            self.textEdit_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
            self.textEdit_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
            self.textEdit_2.setLineWidth(0)
            self.textEdit_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.textEdit_2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
            self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 60, 221, 41))
            self.textEdit_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
            self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
            self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit.setEnabled(True)
            self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 1061, 81))
            self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 140, 101, 31))
            self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_5.setEnabled(True)
            self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 1061, 111))
            self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
            self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 250, 101, 31))
            self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
            self.textEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_6.setEnabled(True)
            self.textEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 330, 1061, 81))
            self.textEdit_6.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.textEdit_6.setObjectName("textEdit_6")
            self.textEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_7.setEnabled(True)
            self.textEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 430, 1061, 121))
            self.textEdit_7.setObjectName("textEdit_7")
            self.textEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
            self.textEdit_8.setEnabled(True)
            self.textEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 560, 1061, 101))
            self.textEdit_8.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.textEdit_8.setObjectName("textEdit_8")
            self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 360, 101, 31))
            self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
            self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 470, 101, 31))
            self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
            self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 600, 101, 31))
            self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
    
            self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
            self.textEdit_3.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;\">Простые линейные структуры </span></p></body></html>"))
            self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Корнеенков Антон IBT-12</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
            self.textEdit_4.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Вариант 8</span></p></body></html>"))
            self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Задание №1</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600;\">Найти длину окружности, площадь круга и объем шара одного и того же заданного радиуса R</span></p></body></html>"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Решение"))
            self.textEdit_5.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Задание №2</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600;\">Составьте алгоритм и программу для определения сдачи после покупки в магазине товара:</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600;\">перчаток стоимостью а руб., портфеля стоимостью b руб., галстука стоимостью с руб. </span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600;\">Исходная сумма выделенная на покупку - d руб. В случае не хватки денег сдача поулчится отрицательной.</span></p></body></html>"))
            self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Решение"))
            self.textEdit_6.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Задание №3</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600;\">Найти первую цифру в десятичной записи четырехзначного натурального числа</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:11pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
            self.textEdit_7.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Задание №4</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Идет 13257-я секунда суток. Определить сколько полных часов (h) и полных минут (m) </span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">прошло к этому моменту и вывести данное значение длительности в часах, минутах и секундах </span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">в следующей форме : HH часов MM минут SS секунд</span></p></body></html>"))
            self.textEdit_8.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Задание №5</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">По номеру квартиры определить, в каком подъезде и на каком этаже эта квартира находится. </span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">Дом пятиэтажный, на каждом по 4 квартиры</span></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
    "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
            self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Решение"))
            self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Решение"))
            self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Решение"))
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**SecondW.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Other(object):
    def setupUi(self, Other):
        Other.setObjectName("Other")
        Other.resize(572, 448)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Other)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -10, 851, 661))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.pushButton56 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Other)
        self.pushButton56.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 350, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton56.setObjectName("pushButton56")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Other)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 181, 31))
        self.textEdit.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Other)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Other)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 190, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Other)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 230, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Other)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 104, 21))
        self.textEdit_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Other)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Other)

    def retranslateUi(self, Other):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Other.setWindowTitle(_translate("Other", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton56.setText(_translate("Other", "Вычислить"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Other", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\">Радиус</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Other", "0"))
```

Comment: Приведите формулу того что вы хотите вычислить. Расскажите в какие поля вы собираетесь вводить данные для расчета и куда, в какое поле, вы хотите разместить результат вычислений.

Comment: так, формула представлена классической формулой длины окружности, где используется значение радиуса, вводимое в textEdit : 2 * r * 3.14, хотел бы вывести результат вычисления в первое поле (lineEdit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Объектно-ориентированное программирование**](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/obektno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie-obshhee-predstavlenie.html).

[**Signals & Slots**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

> QString QTextEdit::[**toPlainText**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText)() const
>
> Возвращает текст редактирования текста как обычный текст.

> text : QString
>
> Установка этого свойства очищает выбор, очищает историю отмен/повторов, перемещает курсор в конец строки и сбрасывает измененное свойство на false. Текст не проверяется при вставке с помощью [**setText**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop)().

```
import sys
import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# ??? from FirstW import Ui_Dialog


#from SecondW import Ui_Other
class Ui_Other(object):
    def setupUi(self, Other):
        Other.setObjectName("Other")
        Other.resize(572, 448)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Other)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -10, 851, 661))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.pushButton56 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Other)
        self.pushButton56.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 350, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton56.setObjectName("pushButton56")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Other)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 181, 31))
        self.textEdit.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Other)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 150, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Other)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 190, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Other)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 230, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Other)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 104, 21))
        self.textEdit_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
    
        self.retranslateUi(Other)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Other)
    
    def retranslateUi(self, Other):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Other.setWindowTitle(_translate("Other", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton56.setText(_translate("Other", "Вычислить"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Other", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\">Радиус</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Other", "0"))
 

class Other(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Other):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pi = math.pi
        
        self.pushButton56.clicked.connect(self.result)
        
    def result(self):
        r = self.textEdit_2.toPlainText()
        
        if r:
             p = 2 * float(r) * self.pi
             self.lineEdit_2.setText(f"p = {p:.3f}")


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Решение', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openSecondW)
        
        self.other = Other()
        
    def openSecondW(self):
         self.other.show() 
         
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]